# If checkmark is on - add object to the array [SWIFT]

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, checkmark

Here is my code, but it doesn't saving user name into array

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // тут проверяем если ячейка уже выбрана то удаляем из массива и убираем чекмарк
    // если не выбрана то добавляем в массив и ставим чекмарк
    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == .checkmark {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        usersInGame.add(cell.textLabel?.text)
    } else {

        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false) //убираем выделение ячейки если не нужно обратное
    let usersInGame: NSMutableArray = []
}
```

I understood that it doesn't work, because when i turn on checkmark code doesn't work. Please help!

Comment: remove the last line`let usersInGame: NSMutableArray = []` because it will again create an empty array

Comment: Is it correct array <var array = [] as Array> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you are creating a new cell and try to retrieve the text. Also, the local `usersInGame` is not needed as pointed out by @Samarth Kejriwal

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath), cell.accessoryType == .checkmark {
        usersInGame.add(cell.textLabel?.text)
    } else {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
}
```

Try this instead. Also, set a breakpoint to ensure that it go into `usersInGame`. Might have some syntax error, I am working on a laptop without XCode.